# Gauge transformation of the gauge-fixing term in the QED action

Tags: electromagnetism, lagrangian-formalism, gauge-theory, gauge

In the classroom my teacher stated that the Gauge-fixing term in the action
$$\frac{1}{2\alpha}\int d^4x (\partial_\mu A^\mu(x))^2$$ 
transforms under $A_\mu(x) \rightarrow A_\mu(x)+\partial_\mu \theta(x)$ as:
$$\frac{1}{\alpha}\int d^4x(\partial_\mu A^\mu(x))(\partial_\nu \partial^\nu \theta(x))$$
when inserting the transformation in the first equation I get the additional term:
$$\int d^4x (\partial_\mu\partial^\mu  \theta(x))^2.$$
I was wondering why this term is null; any hint is appreciated.

EDIT:
It was an infinitesimal transformation: with $\theta$ small higher order of $\theta$ were discarded.

Comment: Maybe it is an infinitesimal transformation, i.e. $\theta$ is assumed to be small, such that only the first-order term in $\theta$ is kept?

Comment: It was an infinitesimal transformation, I modified the question and accepted the only answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you write it as a total divergence? If so, then you can use the divergence theorem to argue that it goes to 0 at the surface, which you can take to infinity.